# MYSQL - How to get missing records in an unorganized table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in MYSQL which is not organized in the best way, but I have to handle it like that.

details

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
plant_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY
state VARCHAR
county VARCHAR
municipality VARCHAR
count INTEGER
```

Each record contains the count of how many specimens of a particular plant are present in a state, or in a county, or in a municipality.

Specimen count records for a plant in a state have the county and municipality fields equal to NULL.
Plant count records in a county have the state field which contains the name of the state it belongs to (there is no foreign key) and the municipality field equal to NULL.
The specimen count records of a plant in a municipality have the state and county fields containing their respective names (without foreign key).

I should check which counties I have the total count of but I don't have any municipal count records. I had thought of a LEFT OUTER JOIN created in the following way, left table with counties count, right table with municipalities count, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
SELECT d1.*, d2.*
FROM details AS d1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN details AS d2 
ON (d1.id != d2.id 
    AND d1.plant_id = d2.plant_id 
    AND d1.county = d2.county 
    AND d1.county IS NOT NULL 
    AND d1.municipality IS NULL
    AND d2.municipality IS NOT NULL
   )
WHERE d2.id IS NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE (not scheme), some sample data as INSERT INTO, desired output for this data, and precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, there might be some syntax mistake as I usually work on MSSQL, but I think this should help you.

```
SELECT  d1.*
FROM    details AS d1 
WHERE   d1.county IS NOT NULL AND d1.municipality is NULL
        AND NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT  * 
            FROM    details d2
            WHERE   d2.plant_id = d1.plant_id AND d2.county = d1.county AND d2.municipality IS NOT NULL
        )
```